# surrealDB rust driver vs the REST api

Tags: rust, surrealdb

Should i use the rust driver for surrealDB or is using the REST api viable.
Asking this since the rust driver has 2x the dependencies that one of my actix-web + diesel projecets have and the comptime is less than pleasant.

The rust driver seems to be in a very early stage so i just feel like implementing some helper functions for the REST api might be better, since i assume that it just returns JSO N (i think but correct me if am wrong) i could just use Serde to make stuff easier.

Answer (score 0):

I work under Win 10 x64 and had several problems with the rust driver dependecies. So I wrote a lib which provides me all the Surreal functionality and uses the Surreal Api. I only use reqwest = "0.11.13" & anyhow="1" inside my Lib.

For the evaluation in my projects i use serde_json = "1.0.91".